# Unable to remove a component from salesforce case page editor

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, app-builder

I created a lightening component, added to the case detail page in salesforce, but now i am unable to delete it. The delete button on the top right corner of the widget is disabled.
But i am able to delete it using the keyboard's delete key.

[image]

Any idea why the delete button is disabled? Or what controls it?
is it something on my end or is it a bug on salesforce side?

Please help.

Comment: Pretty sure there is a permission for that, which would suggest that you may not have the rights to do so.

Comment: But i am able to do it using the delete key on keyboard

Comment: Looks like the component loading spinner code is rendering something over the delete icon?

Comment: yes that was the case.. :)

Comment: please add as answer, will accept and close.